# Subclassing in TypeScript and using more specific properties or methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

In TypeScript, how can I get a more specific subclass of a more generic class to allow referencing more specific properties and methods of that subclass when parent classes define them further up the inheritance tree?

To explain my question, I think this code sums up what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
class Driver {}

class Formula1Driver extends Driver {
  
  useFormula1Skills () {

    console.log('Go go go!')
  
  }
}

class Car {

  public driver: Driver

  constructor(driver: Driver) {

    this.driver = driver;

  }
}

class Formula1Car extends Car {

  constructor(driver: Formula1Driver) {

    super(driver)

    this.driver.useFormula1Skills()
    // TS Error: Property 'useFormula1Skills' does not exist on type 'Driver'.(2339)

  }
}
```

Note the type error above.

A `Car` must have a `Driver`, but a `Formula1Car` must have a `Formula1Driver` and be able to call `Formula1Driver`-specific properties and methods.

I do not want `Driver` to define `useFormula1Skills` for obvious reasons, and figured that by stipulating that a `Formula1Driver` must be passed to the constructor in `Formula1Car`, that the type checker would allow my referencing of the subclass-specific method.

Comment: `this.driver.useFormula1Skills()` throws runtime error

Comment: No [it doesn't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOBLAbgU3tA3gXwFC9EhgDEB7eAWwFdwBGBFdaVADwBdUA7AExgbQyZc0aMOhUIqMpRphaAZQDWiECBgAKAJRZ8IkcFKcIpEKgB0IUgHN1AcgDipaFacuAhLc1ixePAXBQ0ADCYIK60AAOVABGIIjA0NxIAgBccMno4QZGbPBUwGzk6kmM8Gn86NpCYiJsABaIEGYlAtAAvIkZ8ADc4b74hIHS1HQhGKwcPDBjOmLZELn5hfDFXWnDsvRdVeEiEFQR6KulXjXQ9Y3NXWYSUuQjckoqalp9uH6cqADu0BujoepPj8-nIKitNF4gA), it throws a compile error in TS...

Comment: it does cause a runtime error. Please try the code from your question

Comment: The purpose of the link was to show you that it doesn't. Notice "Go go go!" when you click "Run". No Runtime error, just TS complains.

Comment: sorry my bad, I did not provide the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow down (override) the property in the subclass definition:

```
class Formula1Car extends Car {

  constructor(public driver: Formula1Driver) {

    super(driver)

    this.driver.useFormula1Skills()
      
  }
}
```

It wouldn't work the other way arround.

Note that above notation is equivalent to:

```
class Formula1Car extends Car {
  public driver: Formula1Driver
  constructor(driver: Formula1Driver) {
    super(driver)
    this.driver = driver;
    ...
  }
}
```

The reason it works is that Car requires that the driver is Driver and F1Driver indeed is a Driver (note that since Driver does not have any properties, any object can be considered a Driver). When overriding properites, you can safely narrow them down - any kind of Driver can drive a Car, therefore F1Driver is okay to be type of driver in F1Car.

It is a design choice of typescript to be easier to work with but it indeed is supectible to runtime errors like in this case:

```
const vettel = new Formula1Driver();

const astonMartin = new Formula1Car(vettel);

const f1OnTheStreet: Car = astonMartin;

// UH OH!!!
f1OnTheStreet.driver = new Driver();

// remember that f1OnTheStreet is the same instance of F1
astonMartin.driver.useFormula1Skills();
// astonMartin.driver.useFormula1Skills is not a function
```

You cannot make a property that you want to access in the subclass private, but you can make it protected, meaning it cannot be accessed from the outside the class but can be access from a subclass. Note that modifiers must match. If you have a private property in Car, you cannot change (access) it in F1Car. If you have public in Car, you cannot make it private in F1Car.

```
class Car {
  constructor(protected driver: Driver) {}
}

class F1Car extends Driver {
  constructor(protected driver: F1Driver) {
     super(driver);
  }
}
```

This still allows Car to implement something like `switchDrivers` end end up with the same runtime error as above.

To make sure that nobody changes drivers, the property in Car needs to be readonly (and also in the subclasses

```
class Car {
   constructor(public readonly driver: Driver) {}
}
```

Just note that these checks are only compile time so anything can happen if you access them without type checking.

Comment: This works but could you explain a little more as to why? Also, if I wanted the property `driver` to be private, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ignore the question about private; I believe what I need is to use `protected` as this allows subclasses to access.

Comment: What about using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) to unpack the constructor parameters?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOBLAbgU3tA3gXwFC9EhgDEB7eAWwFdwBGBFdaVADwBdUA7AExgbQyZc0aMOhUIqMpRphaAZQDWiECBgAKAJRZ8IkcFKcIpEKgB0IUgHN1AcgDipaFacuAhLc1ixePAXBQ0ADCYIK60AAO8KQcwBzc0NxIAgBccMno4QZGbPBUceTqmEmM8NhpxRnwafzo2NpCYiJsABaIEGYlAtAAvIlVANzhvviEgdLUdCEYrBw8MNM6YtkQuflshZWl5Vhd6GkTsvRV9Ut60BBUEehFe2VeTdCt7Z1VZhJS5JNySipqWsNcH5OKgAO7QQ5TULqEHgyFyWrwLReIA)

Comment: it's all about [proper property declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOBLAbgU3tA3gXwFC9EhgDEB7eAWwFdwBGBFdaVADwBdUA7AExgbQyZc0aMOhUIqMpRphaAZQDWiECBgAKAJRZ8IkcFKcIpEKgB0IUgHN1AcgDipaFacuAhLc1ixePAXBQ0ADCYIK60AAO8KQcwBzc0NxIAgBccMno4QZGbPBUceTqmEmM8NhpxRnwafzo2NpCYiJsABaIEGYlAtAAvIlVANzhvviEgdLUdCEYrBw8MNM6IlExqHGoCV3oaROy9INi2RC5+WyFlaXlWFvV0Lt0tWUN4SIQVBHoRTf1TdCt7Z0qr1+qUhr9-h0bmYJFJyJM5EoVGotMNcH5OKgAO53OF7abqDHY+5yR5aLxAA)

Comment: Doesn't the above make assigning `driver` at the superclass level redundant? In which case we loose that connection between class and subclass? The job of the superclass is to assign `driver` to its list of protected properties, not the job of the subclass. Thank you, by the way, for your help so far...

Comment: well you're right, you can leave it to the parent. i assigned the value to prevent unasigned value error. the check is shallow, unfortunately. you can [add `!` to the prop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOBLAbgU3tA3gXwFC9EhgDEB7eAWwFdwBGBFdaVADwBdUA7AExgbQyZc0aMOhUIqMpRphaAZQDWiECBgAKAJRZ8IkcFKcIpEKgB0IUgHN1AcgDipaFacuAhLc1ixePAXBQ0ADCYIK60AAO8KQcwBzc0NxIAgBccMno4QZGbPBUceTqmEmM8NhpxRnwafzo2NpCYiJsABaIEGYlAtAAvIlVANzhvviEgdLUdCEYrBw8MNM6IlExqHGoCV3obmkTsvSDYtkQuflshZWl5Vhb1dB7dLVlDU3QEFQR6EW39a+t7Z0qmYJFJyJM5EoVGotD5cHhOKgAO73MH7abfKppBHIh5yJ5aeoDIA). or use less strict

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using generics, making the type of driver a type argument:

```js
class Car<TDriver extends Driver> {

  public driver: TDriver

  constructor(driver: TDriver) {

    this.driver = driver;

  }
}

class Formula1Car extends Car<Formula1Driver> {

  constructor(driver: Formula1Driver) {

    super(driver)

    this.driver.useFormula1Skills()
  }
}
```